# gulp compass throws error

Tags: gulp, gulp-compass

I am trying to use `gulp-compass` plugin to convert and minify my scss into css.
However I am getting below error:

> $ gulp compass [02:14:32] Using gulpfile C:\Users\dell\Desktop\sassy -
>   copy\gulpfile.js [02:14:32] Starting 'compass'... [02:14:32] Finished
>   'compass' after 13 ms [02:14:33] LoadError on line ["55"] of C: cannot
>   load such file -- bourbon Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
>
> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Error: Compass failed

This is how my scss file looks like:

.scss file:

```
@import 'bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon';
@import 'bower_components/normalize-css/normalize';
@import 'bower_components/susy/sass/susy';

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Raleway');

@import 'partials/variables';
@import 'partials/base';
@import 'partials/footer';
@import 'partials/header';
@import 'partials/layout';
@import 'partials/modules';
```

Following is gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
    compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('assets/scss/styles.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
      sass: 'assets/sass',
      image: 'images',
      require:['bourbon', 'normalize','susy']
       }))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

I guess its not letting plugins like `bourbon`, `normalize`,`susy` to compile and convert. I might have done some wrong configuration I guess.

Tried installing gems but throws the following error:

`gem install susy`

`gem install bourbon`

```
c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\sassy - Copy>gulp compass
[23:23:59] Using gulpfile c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\sassy - Copy\gulpfile.js
[23:23:59] Starting 'compass'...
[23:23:59] Finished 'compass' after 14 ms
    error assets/sass/styles.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/sassy - Copy/assets/sass
  C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
  C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/susy-2.2.12/sass
  C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bourbon-4.3.4/app/assets/stylesheets)

Compilation failed in 1 files.


events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error:     error assets/sass/styles.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/sassy - Copy/assets/sass
  C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
  C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/susy-2.2.12/sass
  C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bourbon-4.3.4/app/assets/stylesheets)
Compilation failed in 1 files.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is quite simple, the required are Ruby gems, not bower or node libraries.

From the [doc](https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass#require),

> Require the given Ruby library before running commands. This is used to access Compass plugins without having a project configuration file.

If you do not install the Ruby gems, you can require them.

```
gem install  susy
gem install bourbon
```

It seems normalize-css does not have a Ruby gem.

---

The new error:

This question may help you  [Why is Compass is giving me an import error when trying to import partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389013/why-is-compass-is-giving-me-an-import-error-when-trying-to-import-partials), you need to use relative path, otherwise It will search the required Ruby gem path.(I think you have bower packages installed).

So changes `@import 'bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon';` to

`@import './bower_component/..` and all things alike.

Comment: Tried after installing gems but failed. I am attaching trace in the post.

Comment: I think this relative path thing hellped. But can you guide me what to do with the normalize import as it is still throwing an error.

Comment: @AakashThakur Just delete the `normalize` requirement in gulp file, and use the relative path to import it.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to require the Ruby packages when there are npm or bower, which is better for such things.